# Recode a list of variables with mutate(ifelse)

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I'm trying to recode a list of variables in a df. Let's say I have 30 variables, var1, var2, var3 etc, with numerical values (1,2,3, etc). I wat to recode, let's say, 0 for every 1.

Normally, I'd use this code:

```
df1<- df%>%
mutate(gender=ifelse(female==1, 0, gender))
```

But what if I wanna change all the 1s to 0s for not only the "gender" variable, but for a whole list of variables (ex. "gender1", "gender2"...etc.)? What syntax do I use? I'd rather not write a line of code for every variable.

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *changing all ones to zero*? just subtract 1. Also you will have to give a reproducible example and the expected output

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to be unclear. I meant recoding the values of a series of variables all at once. For example, if a "gender" variable is coded with 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1, I want all 1s to become 0 and all 2s to become 1s. I'm very new to the forum and not sure how to create a reproducible example, sorry!

Comment: And you can simply do`gender - 1` and all ones will be 0 and all 2 will be 1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the `tidyverse` package would be helpful. The following is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# sample data
var1 <- sample(0:3, 20, replace = T)
var2 <- sample(0:3, 20, replace = T)
var3 <- sample(0:3, 20, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)

df %>% mutate(across(var1:var3, ~case_when(.x == 0 ~ 4, .x == 1 ~ 5, TRUE ~ as.numeric(.x))))
```

`case_when` is a general version of `if_else`. It allows you to enter multiple conditions. In the example, 0 is recorded as 4, 1 is recorded as 5, and "TRUE" is actually "else".

`mutate` and `across` perform the recording across columns of your choice.